# How do linux break 64bit virtual address?

Tags: memory

Assuming a 4-level page-tables, where the first 3 levels are 9-bits and the last one is 12 bits, then shouldn't the maximum virtual address be 3*9+12=39 bits?

Today i have noticed by accident that my addresses where 47 bits long.
e.g 0x7fb329caa3c0

Comment: http://www.cirosantilli.com/x86-paging/

Comment: On "64-bit architectures" section he talks about 2 disjoint parts, where both parts are greater than 39 bits

Comment: on the Bottom half of the referenced page there is a typo on the range: 00007FFF and not 008FFFFF (007FFFFF is the range for the 56bit implementation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A page addresses 2<sup>12</sup> bytes of memory.  A page table is one page large, and each entry is 8 bytes, so a page table contains 2<sup>9</sup> entries, so a page table addresses 2<sup>21</sup> bytes. A page directory is similar, and so addresses 2<sup>30</sup> bytes. A page directory pointer table (PDPT) is one level higher, and so addresses 2<sup>39</sup> bytes. Lastly, the current Intel architecture has one more level, the PML4, addressing 2<sup>48</sup> bits. I think you are missing this last level in your analysis. Canonical addressing breaks this up into two halves, so you have a lower 2<sup>47</sup>-byte space and an upper 2<sup>47</sup>-byte space.

Comment: Ok, i got the structure that i provided from here: [link](https://lwn.net/Articles/106177/) but as it turns out the pictures shows a three-level page-table not four. (I was counting the page offset within the page-table hierarchy)